# What's Assets in the new Nexus 3

Tags: nexus, nexus3

In the new `Nexus 3`, under Browse, there are `Assets` and `Components`. What's the definition of the Assets?

I can't find it in the doc:http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/index.html

Answer (score 14):

A component in Nexus 3 is an installable unit which is delineated by it's coordinates (such as artifact ID + version number).  In some repository formats there is one file per component, but in others there are multiple files per component. So the UI allows browsing repositories by either components or assets (files).

I'll submit an issue in our bug tracker to have the book provide an full explanation of components vs. assets.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [Nexus Book](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/concepts.html#_the_basics_components_repositories_and_repository_formats):

### Component

- Is a `resource like a library or a framework that is used as part of your software application at run-time`, integration or unit test execution time or required as part of your build process. It could be an entire application or a static resource like an image.

### Assets

- Assets are the material addition to all this metadata.

## Example

For a typical JAR component in a Maven repository which is defined at least by the `POM` and the `JAR` files:

**Components are  -**

```
example-project.pom.sha1
example-project.pom.md5
example-project.pom

example-project.jar.sha1
example-project.jar.md5
example-project.jar

example-project-sources.jar.sha1
example-project-sources.jar.md5
example-project-sources.jar

example-project-javadoc.jar.sha1
example-project-javadoc.jar.md5
example-project-javadoc.jar
```

**Assets are -**

```
example-project.pom.sha1
example-project.pom.md5
example-project.pom

example-project.jar.sha1
example-project.jar.md5
example-project.jar

example-project-sources.jar.sha1
example-project-sources.jar.md5
example-project-sources.jar

example-project-javadoc.jar.sha1
example-project-javadoc.jar.md5
example-project-javadoc.jar

maven-metadata.xml
maven-metadata.xml.md5
maven-metadata.xml.sha1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in [the concepts chapter](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/repository-manager-concepts) of the Nexus Repository Manager 3 documentation. Basically assets are the actual binaries and other files associated to the component. A component can have one or multiple assets and is the overarching aggregation and container for metadata.

Comment: Manfred, there is no single word of "assets" mentioned in the link you given. I did search the whole document before I put up this question.

Comment: Well... that document has been updated since you last searched. I maintain that documentation and added the assets section a while ago and published it for you.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/repository-manager-concepts/components%2C-repositories%2C-and-repository-formats this is where the difference between Component and Asset is explained